# Create a macro in Outlook 2010 to add a simple line of text to the email body

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, macros

I created this macro in MS Word and it works great but it doesn't work when I copied it into an Outlook 2010 macro. any assistance is appreciated.

```
Sub Thanks1()
'
' Thanks1 Macro
'
'
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Thank you for the quote."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.typetext(v=office.11).aspx) you'll see that it's part of `Namespace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, which is specific to Word.

So, in Outlook you first need to get access to the Word Editor; so:

```
Set objDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor 
Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection 
objSel.TypeText Text:="Thank you for the quote."
```

Comment: That did it... thank you very much for your help!!